# Why is that get 0.8999999999999999 as the output of System.out.println(0.3+0.6) in Java?

Tags: java, println

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(0.3+0.6);
}
}
```

The output of the above java code is 0.8999999999999999. Why is that?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Same reason as you would write 1/3 as 0,333333333333